# Usando Codeigniter dentro do Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter, htaccess

Estou trabalhando em um blog no qual dentro de uma página específica ele tem um iframe que aponta para dentro do próprio servidor, chamando uma pasta que contém o CodeIgniter rodando.

Até alguns dias tudo funcionava, isso no servidor antigo.
Tive que trocar de servidor e no servidor atual ele não funciona.
A única página que ele abre é a página configurada no codeigniter para ser a inicial, quando necessito acessar um controller recebo um erro 404.

O Wordpress tenta acessar uma pasta, e realmente essa pasta não existe, por exemplo eu informo a seguinte url:
**servidor.com.br/codeigniter/controller/action/**

Ao invés de entrar no controller e procurar a ação ele procura por pastas e obviamente estas pastas não existe, eu criei pastas com esses caminhos e ele conseguiu a index que coloquei dentro da pasta "action", mas isso não é o que necessito. Eu preciso que ele se comporte como um framework.

Eu preciso de uma forma de que quando eu apontar para servidor.com.br/codeigniter/ ele entenda que não é mais para se comportar como se fosse do blog, e começar a se comportar como um framework.

Eu não entendo nada de .htaccess é um dos meus piores pontos como programador, tentei boa parte do dia arrumar uma solução com o htaccess, porém, como podem ver não tive nenhum sucesso, não tenho certeza se a maneira correta de resolver esse problema seria com htaccess, mas foi a única possível saída que encontrei.

Segue htaccess do wordpress:

```
\# BEGIN WordPress<br/>
< IfModule mod_rewrite.c> <br/>
RewriteEngine On <br/>
RewriteBase /<br/>
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]<br/>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f<br/>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d<br/>
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]<br/>
< /IfModule> <br/>
\# END WordPress
```

E também htaccess do codeigniter

```
RewriteEngine on<br/>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f<br/>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d<br/>
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]<br/>
```

Se eu entrar no codeigniter direto por um subdomínio o programa roda perfeitamente, porém, eu não posso acessar o iframe com um subdomínio, pois preciso recuperar dados/variáveis de dentro do iframe com jQuery/Ajax, se eu utilizar um subdomínio isso não é possível, necessito de uma forma que faça o blog entender que quando for servidor.com.br/codeigniter ele comece a utilizar o htaccess do codeigniter, ou então, ele entre nos controllers ao invez de procurar por pastas, (creio que essa seja a solução.)

Answer (score 2):

Consegui resolver meu problema, precisei descobrir algumas novas funções do `.htaccess` que eu não conhecia, o problema é que estou com muitas dúvidas em mente e não consigo matar as dúvidas no Google, fazer o que...

Segue a minha resolução, talvez ajude alguém.

O `.htaccess` do framework ficou dessa forma:

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /online/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

1. Precisei adicionar o RewriteBase para ele redirecionar a pasta raiz do framework.
2. Aparentemente no RewriteRule eu passei o index do framework e os parametros de controller/action.
3. A primeira linha não sei para que serve.